# Focus on TextInput from imported Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-text

I have a `TextInput` in my Component (`FirstComponent`). I can call the focus on it from the component by calling the `this.refs`. I am also importing and calling another Component (`SecondComponent`) which also needs to focus on the `TextInput` on a button click.

My First Component:

```
Import SecondComponent from './SecondComponent';

<View>
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=>this.refs.MyBox.focus()}  
    >
        <Text>Open</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>


    <SecondComponent />


    <TextInput
      ref='MyBox'
      style={{width: '100%', borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
    />

</View>
```

The `SecondComponent` too has a `TouchableOpacity` to call the focus on the `TextInput`:

```
<View>
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=>this.refs.MyBox.focus()}  
    >
        <Text>Open</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

The SecondComponent is rendered fine but cannot call the focus on the `TextInput` since it's not in the SecondComponent. How do I resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass the reference to the `TextInput` directly:

```
<SecondComponent textInput={this.refs.MyBox} />
```

And then in `SecondComponent` call `this.props.textInput.focus()`, or you can pass in the function that does the focusing and invoke it within the second component:

```
focusOnTextInput = () => this.refs.MyBox.focus();

<View>
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.focusOnTextInput}>
    ...
    <SecondComponent onPress={this.focusOnTextInput}/>
```

And then in `SecondComponent`:

```
onPress={this.props.onPress}
```

Comment: The second option works like a charm! Thank you master!

Answer (score 1):

Refs of component cannot call from another component. In your case you need to setup method in parent component which takes a component need to focus, and focused it. And then you pass this method as props to child components.

```
focusMethod(component) {
 component.focus()
}

this.props.focusMethod(this.refs.MyBox);
```